# How to use existing SSH key on my newly installed Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, github

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 on my machine. 
Now I want to use my existing ssh key on my machine, so that I can use GitHub with my previous activities.

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you have a copy of your ssh keys (*e.g.*, on a USB stick) then simply copy the key files to the `~/.ssh/` directory.

*E.g.*,

```
cp /path/to/my/key/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa
cp /path/to/my/key/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
# change permissions on file
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
# start the ssh-agent in the background
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
# make ssh agent to actually use copied key
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Otherwise, you will need to create a new one and add it to your GitHub account https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/. Be sure to remove the old key from GitHub while you're at it.

Comment: Thank You @amc

How can i copy from github to my machine ?

Comment: If you don't already have a copy of the key, then you will need to create a new one and add it to your GitHub account https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Comment: So, i have to create a new SSH key and add that to github, isn't it. and i have to delete the previous SSH key from github, i had created earlier.

Comment: yes, it sounds like you don't have a copy of you key files so you just need to make new ones and remove the old key.

Comment: Just dropping a short note to mention that the permissions on both files need to be set to 600 eg. -rw------- example: 

    chmod 600 id_rsa* 

The default file permissions for copy pasting them there won't work.

Comment: The perms on the public key are not as critical as the private key - the system will permit the public key to be world-readable while it will not permit the private key to be,

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: Give permission to ssh folder

`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`

Step 2: Give permission to ssh key files

`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

`chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Step 3: Run the below command on the client machine, that will add the SSH key to the agent.

`ssh-add`

Now you can confirm with `ssh-add -l` (again on the client) that it was indeed added.